# Blender Rigify: automatic weights incorrectly deforming my mesh

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I'm making a human character, rigging with the rigify addon, but when I generated the rig and parented with automatic weights, everything on the body deformed terribly. I usually don't have this problem when I rig. I've tried applying all transforms on my mesh, and setting origin to geometry with both the mesh and armature, but the result is still the same. Not pictured, but when I apply the scale transforms to my mesh (if I needed to do that in order to fix the problem), it also scales up the hair particles attached to the head. Help is greatly needed lol.

[image]

Comment: Automatic weights only provide you with a starting point.  Sometimes the starting point is good enough, but most times you need to weight paint to tune the weights to what you need.

Comment: It may be the weights, or it may be the rig.  Look at your tweak bones (blue circles.)  My guess is you have a bunch of bones set up as bendy bones that aren't acting as they should.  I've seen this problem with a lot of Rigify users lately, not sure if there was an update to Rigify that changed the workflow or what.

Comment: @Nathan How would you check to see if bones have been set up as bendy bones? And there was an update for rigify, but only a face update. Thanks

Comment: I would change the display from octohedral to bendy bone, and disable shapes, and look for any segmented bendy bones.  Or, you could inspect your deforming bones and look in bones/bendy bones/segments and look for anything with more than 1 segment.

Comment: @MartyFouts , I see what you're saying, but this is a new problem with me as I usually don't have to weight paint everything. every single bone except the face bones seem to be going wrong. the weight paint shows that the left side is assigned to the right side instead, and vise versa. An axis problem? It would take a tedious amount of time to weight paint every bone from deforming how it is now, and I've even tried that, and it still has an ugly deformation.

Comment: Can you check the normals of your mesh? I've seen this type of problem and it has to do with inverted normals. If you can't, I'll try to provide info.
Also share your blend, if that's an option.

Comment: @CGDive I found out the problem, it had to do with applying the scale transforms as well as what you said, flipping the normals after. Case closed!